# Directory is not being created even after seeking Storage permission

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am just trying to create a directory seeking required permission including permissions in manifest but still directory is not being created.

**Here is my code below-**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(haveStoragePermission()) {

        File new_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Images");
        if (!new_folder.exists()) {
            new_folder.mkdirs();
            boolean k=   new_folder.mkdirs();
         if (k)
         {
          Toast.makeText(this,"Directory created successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to create directory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        
    }


}
```

Comment: Mohit told you already that the file could not be created. `new_folder.mkdirs();` But.. before that that folder is not created. And you dont know as you dont check the return value of mkdirs().

Comment: Yes I has also ask for permission before, I have Edited my question now you can also see my user permission function.

Comment: ???? You still are not checking the return value of mkdirs(). Do it and tell what happens. And yet better: check if the folder exists before you call your async task. Dont loose yourself in permissions. You should first write good code so you know that you cannot create a directory to begin with. And knowing that you would also know that starting your async task then is to no avail.

Comment: So remove all code and post only code where you try to create that directory. As that is your problem.

Comment: Yes, just checked it as you suggested, it returns false, I don't understand why even after seeking permission successfully.

Comment: I will tell you when you have removed all code and only post code for creating a directory. With the right problem description. And a right subject for your post.

Comment: Ok. But your are still not checking the return value of mkdirs(). And of course you should display a Toast() to inform the user when it fails to create the directory. And then return.

Comment: Not that it matters for your problem but `File new_folder = new File("sdcard/Download/Images");` should be: `File new_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Images");`

Comment: Now you see I have also added a Toast and it still returns false as If I write File ```new_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Images");```

Comment: I told you that that would not solve your problem . Only better code. So of course mkdirs() still returns false. And why not updating your code here too with that statement?

Comment: But... The problem happens to you because you use an Android 10 device. Or not?

Comment: Yes, It is actually Android 10.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot to find out how to do this, Actually problem was with android 10 way of seeking permission.

Comment: Yes. We knew that from the start as you are #653 that reported this problem the last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with **Android 10 permissions**, it's bit different here to seek permission in manifest where we need to add following line to **manifest.xml**- **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** as mentioned below-

```
<application>
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" 
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with respect to the File downloading. The issue is you don't have permission to access storage. Please check the error.

```
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So seems like File could not be created. You may need to check if you have the permission to write storage. If you don't want to ask that permission you can go for creating the file in the internal storage.

You should call it like this

```
if(haveStoragePermission()) {
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    downloadTask.execute("https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/tiny-png-panda.jpg");
}
```

Comment: But I have already mentions following permissions in manifest.xml  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: Have you prompted the user for permission? Has the user allowed permission? You can check that in App Info -> Permissions.

Comment: I have Edited my question now you can also see my user permission function. I have also checked that in Appliaction Manager, Storage permission was showing allowed

Comment: Your MainActivity does not show the call for storage permission function. Maybe you are calling it before loading this activity. But a better approach is asking for it when you need it. There is a possibility that user may have revoked the permission.

Comment: Sorry, I just missed to mention that while editing, now you can see I have called the function at the very beginning of onCreate method. I ensured the  permission is allowed inside App manager Permission section.

Comment: @ErenYeager - you must use the return value of the permission function. If it is false you must not trigger the download. I edited my answer for the same. You can debug and check on the device if you are getting the return value as true. Also, my understanding is you must call the things after views are created and not in onCreate.

Comment: Yes, did the same, it returned false, even after seeking permission.

Comment: Yeah you need to find a reason to fix the permission. Why we are not getting the permission. As I already said, my understanding is this should not be done in onCreate. Any modification to UI or API call must be done only after the UI is created.

Comment: Thank you for being here, the problem was actually Android 10's way of seeking permission.